# CentOS 5.2: GLibC version too old (libgio issue), upgrade to which GLibC version

Tags: linux, centos, centos-5, glibc

I'm working on a CentOS 5.2 system.
The application I'm trying to launch, refuses because a reference to `libgio-2.0.so.0` seems not to exist.

This seems to be due to the GLibC version, so I had thought of upgrading this, and as I need to upgrade anyway, why not take the most recent version 2.23?
Well, unfortunately, GLibC 2.23 seems not to support CentOS 5.2.

On the other hand, I have already upgraded much other libraries (GCC,GDB, binutils, Texinfo, MakeInfo, ...) to recent versions, and an upgrade to, let's say GLibC 2.6, is complaining about the fact that those other libraries are too recent.

Instead of continuing in a trial-and-error mode, I'd like to know what is the highest GLibC version I can install on a CentOS 5.2 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm working on a CentOS 5.2 system.

The current version of CentOS 5 is 5.11.  You have and absurdly out of date system.

> libgio-2.0.so.0 seems not to exist.

On CentOS 6 and newer, that is provided by the glib2 package.  The glib2 package in CentOS 5 does not provide that.  Save yourself the hassle and just upgrade to CentOS 6 or 7.

> Well, unfortunately, GLibC 2.23 seems not to support CentOS 5.2.

That's not how CentOS works.  The versions of most applications are essentially frozen, and then they receive backported security fixes.  [This page](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) explains it all.  Upgrading package outside of the system packages is not recommended and will often result in a severely broken system.

> On the other hand, I have already upgraded much other libraries (GCC,GDB, binutils, Texinfo, MakeInfo, ...) to recent versions, and an upgrade to, let's say GLibC 2.6, is complaining about the fact that those other libraries are too recent.

Like I said, a severely broken system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my application was referring to libglass.so, which was in its turn called upon by JFRT.jar java package.
The usage of this package, however, is not essential to my application (it's only used for rendering and displaying HTML messages, which is not essential), so we have decided to remove that part of the application.

My application still contains references to JFRT.jar, but as that jar-file is  only dynamically loaded, we can use workaround for this (by this the usefulness of dynamic loading is again demonstrated :-) )